# Two ContextMenu's in Same Activity/Fragment

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have two `ContextMenu`'s in same `Activity` or `Fragment`.

Here is `onCreateContextMenu` where I handle them both:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Available Actions");

    if (v == listView) {

        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        position = info.position;

        menu.add(2, 1, 1, "Edit");
        menu.add(2, 2, 2, "Delete");
        menu.add(2, 3, 3, "Share");

    }


    if (v == iPP) {

        menu.add(1, 4, 1, "Pick From Gallery");
        menu.add(1, 5, 2, "Capture Picture");
        menu.add(1, 6, 3, "Remove");


    }

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

}
```

When I lick on the `listView` one, it inflates "Edit, Delete, Share" just fine.  But when I click on iPP, it Inflates all 6 choices for both `iPP` and `listView`?

Can anyone see what is going on?

Note:  `iPP` is an `ImageView`

Comment: `ContextMenu.add(...)` simply adds items to any that already exist. In each of your `if` conditional blocks, call `menu.clear()` before adding the items.

Comment: I would suggest you to use the `ContextualActionBar` insted, it seems to fit more in your case.

Comment: @Squonk Well the problem is whenever `iPP` is the view, it for some reason calls the wrong three second (from the `listView`).   So `menu.clear(),`  clears the incorrect three. Not sure why onCreateContext seems to be triggered as second time.

Comment: I'm starting to think because `iPP` is part of the ListView header, it calls the `listView`'s menu as well.

Comment: @KickingLettuce : Looking at your code again, you shouldn't be using `==` to compare objects. Use either `if (v.equals(listView)) {...}` and `if (v.equals(iPP)) {...}` (for example). Or use `if (v.getId() == R.id.myListViewId) {...}` and `if (v.getId() == R.id.myImageViewId) {...}`.

Comment: @Squonk  I've tried it both way with same result.  I think because my `ImageView` is a child view of my `ListView` header, it triggers both my `registerForContext` calls.

Comment: @KickingLettuce : OK, if that's the case then perhaps you need to use `if(...) else` with whichever object needs to take priority in the `if` block and the other in the `else` block. At the moment you're using `if` for the `iPP` object even if the `if` condition for `listView` is true.

Comment: @Squonk  Thanks for your help on this.  Unforetuately, I tried that too... that indicates to me, onCreateContextMenu gets run twice when I click on imageView in header of listView.  But only ONCE when I click on listView itself.

Comment: @KickingLettuce : Sorry I can't think of any other ideas - having a separate context menu for a header isn't something I've ever tried to do. It sounds like you're right and it's triggering twice but I can't think of a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  It seems like a bug maybe?  I ran into something similar like this before and @Commonsware end up reporting it.  Had to do with headers and ContextMenu's as well.  I've tried workarounds by setting some booleans's etc, nothing.  Oh well.  May have to redesign.

Comment: @Squonk  Got a workaround .. answer coming below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling two `registerForContextMenu()`'s.  One for `iPP`, one for `listView`.  Since `iPP` was technically a part of the `listView`, it was in the `header`, BOTH of my registers were calling.  So I just played by the rules and tested for `listView` `position` instead of `View` type.

```
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Available Actions");
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        position = info.position;
        ListView lv = (ListView) v;
        int firstVisible = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View rowView = lv.getChildAt(position - firstVisible);

        if (position > 0) {
                    // if NOT in header
                } else {
                    // if Part of Header
                }
```

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it (or at least worked around it). I'll remember that if I ever need to do something similar.